# is there a way of reshaping a numpy array of size (1235) from a 1D to something like 2D

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I did write this code and i got the message below

```
x = np.reshape(x,(1235,3))
```

> Value Error: cannot reshape array of size 1235 into shape (1235,3)

Comment: What is the shape of x?

Comment: its because 1235 is not same as x.shape[0]*x.shape[1]

Comment: shaoe of x is 1235